# Average of 5 vectors that they are 20-D

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am just trying to write down the equation for this operation I describe on the title.

So suppose the we have these vectors:

$v1=[q_{1,1}, q_{1,2}, ... , q_{1,20}]$

$v2=[q_{2,1}, q_{2,2}, ... , q_{2,20}]$

.

.

$v5=[q_{5,1}, q_{5,2}, ... , q_{5,20}]$

I came up with this equation:

$$\frac{1}{5}\sum_{i=1}^{20}\sum_{j=i}^{5} q_{i,j}$$

So I was wondering if this is correct, at least on matlab i am getting the correct output, but can it be re-written differently / more efficiently?

Thanks

Comment: The average of $n$ entities is another entity of the same type, in this case, a 20-dimensional vector.  Yet you have arrived at a scalar.  You have arrived at the sum of the components of the averaged vector, not at what your title describes.

Comment: You also seem to have flipped $i$ and $j$ and your summation, given your definition of $v1,\ldots,v5$.

Comment: @qman yeah exactly, my final result is a 1x20 vector, not a scalar. Not sure how to write this down formally .

Comment: Your summation over twenty values is not how you express a vector.  However you could write ${v}=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{i=1}^5 v_i=\frac{1}{5}[\sum_{i=1}^5 q_{i,1},\ldots,\sum_{i=1}^5 q_{i,20}]$.

Comment: @qman oh thank! makes things much clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just described them in terms of $v_i$:

$$\frac15 \sum_{i=1}^5 v_i$$

or $\bar{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{20 \times 1}$, where $\bar{v}_j = \frac15\sum_{i=1}^5 q_{ij}$ where $j \in \{ 1, \ldots, 20\}$.

Comment: Looks good! Thanks a lot

Comment: You forgot an overline in the sum.

Comment: overline? hmm.. I think i am a bit lost.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh, what is the difference beetwen $v_i$ and $\overline{v_i}$?

Comment: $v_i$ is the $i$-th element of $v$, $\bar{v}_i$ is the $i$-th element of $\bar{v}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $u = (1,1,...,1)$ ($20$ ones) then you can write:

$$ \overline{v} = {1\over 5} \sum_{i=1}^5 v_i\cdot u$$

Comment: my $u$'s are not ones though.

Comment: It is a scalar product $v_i\cdot u = q_{i,1}+q_{i,2}+...+q_{i,n}$